# How do I assign variable values from the class to objects created in that class?

Tags: java, variables

I have a food class form which I am creating some food objects, for the sake of this question I will only include one food object. Basically, I have declared two variables in my food class, healthGain and wasteGain (integers), and I want each new food instance created from this class to have a unique value for each of these. For example, one of my foods will be hay and this has a health value of +1 and a waste value of 4. How would I do this?

```
public class Food {

   int healthGain;
   int wasteGain;

   Food hay = new Food():

   //hay healthGain = +1
   //hay wasteGain = 4
}
```

Comment: Just don't do it in the class body. And watch the recursion.

Comment: check tutorials on object oreitned programming

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Food{

    int healthGain;
    int wasteGain;

    public static void main(String [] a){

        Food hay = new Food();
        hay.healthGain = 1;
        hay.wasteGain = 4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Food {

   private int healthGain;
   private int wasteGain;
   public Food(int healthGain,int wasteGain){
       this.healthGain=healthGain;
       this.wasteGrain=wasteGain;
   }
   public int getHealhGain(){
   return healthGain;
   }
   public int getWasteGain(){
   return wasteGain;
   }
  // Provide getter and setter

}
public class FoodTest{
    public static void main(String args[]){
     Food badfood=new Food(12,-100);
     Food goodFood=new Food(1000,1);
     System.out.println("The healthGain and wasteGain on badFood is:"+badfood.getHealthGain()+" "+badfood.getWasteGain()+" ,But the healthGain and wastegain on goodFood is: "+goodFood.getHealthGain()+" "+goodFood.getWasteGain());

  }
}
```

Explanation: The badfood and goodFood are the instances and each of them has different values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to always have the same value then you can declare that in your constructor:

```
       Food(){
           healthGain = 1;
           wasteGain =4;
      }
```

Now whenever you create an instance of food it will automatically set those variables to those values. If you want to have the option to set them to different values create a constructor as such

```
        Food(int h, int w){
                  healthGain =h;
                wasteGain = w;
         }
```

Then in your main class you can create it using:

```
       Food hay = new Food(1, 4);
```

and it will assign those values to the corresponding members.

You can also create getters and setter to change the values whenever you need, not just upon instantiating the objects.